# Simple npm module allowing users to create Sets of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm a junior developer and I've recently created a simple npm module that was designed to allow users to create Sets of objects in JavaScript. This was done by implementing a single class `ObjectSet` that would provide all of the functionality that I needed. This class made use of an attribute called innerMap that I would like to have kept private. However, I'm not sure what is the best approach for making a private variable is in this situation.

From what I've researched, the ES5/older way of making a private variable would be to define a variable in the function constructor and defining all functions that use that private variable in the constructor as well. However, the problem with this approach is that there would be a significant memory overhead associated with doing so, right? You are defining all of the functions directly on the returned object, instead of the object's prototype and making use of prototypal inheritance. In other words, you end up storing multiple copies of the same function in memory (the function is stored once for each and every object). Is there any way to avoid this memory overhead?

A second problem that I have is that even if I can accept the memory overhead of the previous method of making private variables, I can't find a clean way of doing so using the ES6 class syntax. Using the ES5 way of making a variable private using ES6 class syntax means that I would have to define all of the functions in the constructor.

Example:

```
class ObjectSet {
    constructor(){
        let privateVar = 'private';
        this.privateGetter = () => privateVar;
        this.privateSetter = (newVal) => {privateVar=newVal;};
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of making a variable private in ES6? Or did I misunderstand something about how memory works with JavaScript objects/prototypal inheritance?

My code for the `ObjectSet` class can be found [here](https://github.com/keithlee96/object-set-js/blob/master/object-set.js). In my npm module, I would have liked to make the object attribute `innerMap` private, but I couldn't find a way to do it cleanly and ended up simply not making it private. I'm open to getting any sort of constructive criticism on the code that I've written.

Note: I am aware that the ES6 class syntax is just syntactic sugar for prototypal inheritance, I don't need that concept explained to me again.

Here is the code for `ObjectSet`:

```
const { cloneDeep, isEqual } = require('lodash');
const objectHash = require('object-hash');
const assert = require('assert');
const isIterable = require('./helpers/isIterable');
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
// Note: never return objects to the user, until they are removed
// Whenever an object is inserted into the set, a deep copy of it is made.
// Once hashed, the copied object is never exposed to the outside world

module.exports = class ObjectSet {
  /* Constructor accepts an array of objects to add and deepCopy is a boolean to determine
  if it's necessary to deepCopy all inserted objects */
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
  constructor(arg = [], { cloneDeep } = { cloneDeep: true }) {
    if (!isIterable(arg)) {
      throw new Error('ObjectSet constructor recieved a non iterable argument');
    }
    this.size = 0;
    this.innerMap = new Map();
    this.cloneDeep = cloneDeep;

    for (const obj of arg) {
      this.add(obj);
    }
  }
  /* Allows users to add objects to set */
  add(obj, ...extraObj) {
    const objClone = this.cloneDeep ? cloneDeep(obj) : obj;
    const hash = objectHash(objClone);
    const objArr = this.innerMap.get(hash);
    if (objArr === undefined) {
      this.innerMap.set(hash, [objClone]);
      this.size++;
    } else {
      assert(Array.isArray(objArr));
      let alreadyInserted = false;
      for (const insertedObj of objArr) {
        if (isEqual(objClone, insertedObj)) {
          alreadyInserted = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!alreadyInserted) {
        objArr.push(objClone);
        this.size++;
      }
    }
    extraObj.forEach(o => this.add(o));
    return this;
  }

  /* Returns true if this object contains another */
  has(obj) {
    const hash = objectHash(obj);
    const objArr = this.innerMap.get(hash);
    if (objArr === undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    for (const insertedObj of objArr) {
      if (isEqual(obj, insertedObj)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  delete(obj) {
    const hash = objectHash(obj);
    const objArr = this.innerMap.get(hash);
    if (objArr === undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
      if (isEqual(obj, objArr[i])) {
        // remove the object
        const [objRef] = objArr.splice(i, 1);
        this.size--;
        if (objArr.length === 0) {
          // If the array is empty, remove it from the map
          this.innerMap.delete(objectHash(objRef));
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  clear() {
    this.innerMap.clear();
    this.size = 0;
    return this;
  }

  entries() {
    return [...this]
      .map(obj => [this.cloneDeep ? cloneDeep(obj) : obj, this.cloneDeep ? cloneDeep(obj) : obj]);
  }

  forEach(callback, thisArg) {
    const cb = callback.bind(thisArg || this);
    for (const obj of this) {
      cb(this.cloneDeep ? cloneDeep(obj) : obj);
    }
  }

  keys() {
    return this.values();
  }

  values() {
    return this[Symbol.iterator]();
  }

  * [Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (const [, objArr] of this.innerMap) {
      for (const obj of objArr) {
        yield this.cloneDeep ? cloneDeep(obj) : obj;
      }
    }
  }

  toString() {
    return `ObjectSet(${[...this]})`;
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look into `WeakMap`s, they are commonly used for this. MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap -- SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413222/what-are-the-actual-uses-of-es6-weakmap